# Why we need the same number of equations and variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I once read that to solve a system of equations, I need $n$ equations for $n$ variables.

I think I read it in a work by Euler. However, I have never managed to find a demonstration of this.
 So, why is this true? What is the demonstration for any system of equations? I would appreciate a formal proof and another intuitive one, thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your question for _linear equations_ is the substance of the first part of most standard linear algebra courses. An answer here would just echo that material. You can start at the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Answer (score 2):

It's not true in general.

Let $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ where $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, 100\}$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i^2 =0.$$

We have $100$ variables and only one equation and we can solve it uniquely. That is $\forall i \in \{ 1, \ldots, 100\}, x_i=0$.

Comment: Well, the solution is unique in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Just change $x_i^2$ to $\left|x_i\right|$.

Comment: @user202729 There's a deep difference between equations involving "nice" algebraic functions such as polynomials and those involving functions like taking the absolute value and similar functions. In the first case, the "$n$ equations for $n$ variables" can be formally understood in terms of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Siong, can you explain me that, please?

Comment: For the example that I constructed for real numbers, we know that for real number $x_i$, we have $x_i^2 \ge 0$. If the sum of the squared terms is zero, then each term must be zero. I just constructed an example where we have one equation and multiple variables and yet it can be solved uniquely. In terms of linear algebra, if the $n$ equations are independent, then the coefficient matrix is invertible and we can invert a matrix.